# command not available in bash script

Tags: shell-script, bashrc

My company has a custom tool we install in Linux to upload files to a server (among other things) called `oTools`. When I open a new Terminal, I can run (from any folder) `oTools upload file` and *file* is uploaded to the server.

However, the tool doesn't have an option to upload several files at once. So I'm trying to build a bash script to do that. Here is the code I built

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in ./folder/*
do
  oTools upload $file
done
```

But I'm having the following error:

> ./upload-all.sh: oTools: not found

I've checked my file `.bashrc` and it contains the path to oTools:

```
alias oTools="/home/user/folder/oTools-cli"
```

I've tried also to put the complete path on my script (the path above, that is on `.bashrc` file), but I'm getting the same issue. I tried doing the same code using `ls` instead of my installed tool and it worked...

So, how can I make bash script to recognize my custom tool?

Comment: Double-quote that variable `"$file"` when you use it. Otherwise your code will break unexpectedly when you use a filename that contains a character special to the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write a script, it doesn't typically pull in your aliases.

You might consider specifying the command explicitly in your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
oTools="/home/user/folder/oTools-cli"
for file in ./folder/*
do
    ${oTools} upload "${file}"
done
```

Answer (score 5):

You're facing at least two problems:

- Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the `expand_aliases` shell option is set using `shopt`.
- `.bashrc` usually holds configuration for interactive shells, not for scripts (aka non-interactive shells).

There are some solutions:

```
# Set expand_aliases option and add the alias (in your script)
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias oTools="/home/user/folder/oTools-cli"

# Create a function instead of an alias (in your script)
oTools() { /home/user/folder/oTools-cli "$@"; }

# Add /home/user/folder to your PATH (in your .profile)
PATH="/home/user/folder:$PATH"
```

Comment: Some of this _may fail_ because the OP has declared `#!/bin/sh` rather than `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: `expand_aliases` I learn something useful every day....

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue i ran into when running scripts via cron. I am not sure if it applies here, but here try adding your path at the beginning of the script. Something like...

```
    #!/bin/bash

    PATH="/your/path"
    ...
```

Comment: You want to set `PATH=/your/path:$PATH` perhaps, or more safely `PATH=/your/path:/usr/bin:/bin`. Otherwise, you won't have access to standard programs (cat, ls, find, sed, awk...).